# What is the difference in between these two launching options, and how can I fix it?

Tags: unity, launcher, eclipse

I have to launch my `eclipse` with first setting `LC_MESSAGES=C` (long story, I need this variable, otherwise I will loose some functionality).

So, if I run eclipse from terminal:

```
$ LC_MESSAGES=C /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Everything works perfectly.

However, I wish to run it from the launcher, so I created a launcher script in `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env LC_MESSAGES=C /usr/bin/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
```

In spite of defining *LC_MESSAGES* in this launcher, it seems it's not setting it actually (my functions depending on this variable are not working).

What is the difference in between these 2 launches, and how can I make the second one working the exact same way as the first one?

OS is Ubuntu22.04LTS.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a second .desktop file (in `~/.local/share/applications` for example) that is taking priority over your modified one?

Comment: That directory doesn't contain any files related to `eclipse`, and when I modify the one in `/usr/share/applications`, icon is removed from the launcher, then gets re-added. (Removed if I make a typo, and re-added if I correct it). So I think there is nothing else for this launcher, just the single one in `/usr/share/applications`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Exec line looks good so I have no idea why this does not work but there is an easy method to get it to work: create a wrapper

```
$ sudo cat /opt/eclipse/eclipse2
```

and add

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_MESSAGES=C 
exec /usr/bin/eclipse "$@"
```

save and use that

```
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse2
```

(I used eclipse2 as I expect there will already be an eclipse file there; change it to what you want that to be).

Comment: `./opt/eclipse/eclipse2` works, however when launched from the launcher icon, it is *not* working. :(